# I have this black line that can't be pressed on and not connected to anything, and I don't know how to remove it

Tags: modeling

[image: here in the white circle you can see the black line]

I have no idea how to remove it , or if it will affect the project.
help, thanks T.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to exit from *Edit Mode* to *Object Mode*. click on the line to select the object containing it. Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> again to edit the mesh. Make sure the *Edge Select* mode is enabled: [image] - now click on the edge, press <kbd>X</kbd> (or <kbd>DEL</kbd>) for deletion and choose *"Edges"*.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!!!!!!!! <3